# Set time out limit for a SOAP Request on the client side delphi?

Tags: delphi, soap, firemonkey

My web services are written in delphi. Sometimes some of them take long to respond. I want to set a 30 seconds time out period for them on the client side. 
Given that all my server calls are made through seperate thread, how I can achieve the time out setting.

I am currently using `THTTPRIO` for HTTP request.

Answer (score 3):

First if you haven't set your timeouts:

```
var
  MyRIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  MyRio := ... 
  MyRIO.HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout:=x; 
  MyRIO.HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout :=x; 
  MyRIO.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout:=x; 
end;
```

If that doesn't work, dig further.

As far as I know, the problem with THTTPRIO is that, at least on Windows, it uses or used to use WinINET, and WinINET has many underlying bugs in it, including inability to respect any timeouts that are requested. For this reason, I moved away from anything that uses WinINET.  What version of Delphi are you using? I think at some point, THTTPRIO may have moved from WinINET (which is crap) to WinHTTP (which is good), but depending on your Delphi version, you may want to check what is happening under the hood.  On Android, and on iOS, of course, and on Mac firemonkey, WinINET is not a possibility, but if you're testing on Windows and it's glitching, consider that possibility. I believe that by Delphi XE8 and 10 Seattle, that WinINET is not used by default for THTTPRIO, but I can't find the docs on this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what component you use for your communication.

I use a THTTPReqResp for my SOAP communication and do this:

```
constructor TEWSSOAPMessage.Create(AWebserviceURL,AUserName,APassword: String; AExchangeTimeOutConnect,AExchangeTimeOutSend,AExchangeTimeOutReceive: Integer);
begin
   FSoapRequest := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
   FSoapRequest.Position := 0;
   FSoapResponse := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
   FSoapResponse.Position := 0;

   FReqResp := THTTPReqResp.Create(nil);
   FReqResp.URL := AWebserviceURL;
   FReqResp.UserName := AUserName;
   FReqResp.Password := APassword;
   if AExchangeTimeOutConnect > 0 then FReqResp.ConnectTimeout := AExchangeTimeOutConnect;
   if AExchangeTimeOutSend    > 0 then FReqResp.SendTimeout    := AExchangeTimeOutSend;
   if AExchangeTimeOutReceive > 0 then FReqResp.ReceiveTimeout := AExchangeTimeOutReceive;
   ...
end;
```

This leaves default timeouts if I specify 0.
I fill FSoapRequest and then when I 'execute' my TEWSSOAPMessage:

```
procedure TEWSSOAPMessage.Execute;
begin
   try
      FExecTime := GetTickCount;
      FReqResp.Execute(FSoapRequest,FSoapResponse);
      FExecTime := GetTickCount - FExecTime;
      ...
   except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
         // WinINet error codes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.serviceerror%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx
         if (E is ESOAPHTTPException) and (ESOAPHTTPException(E).StatusCode = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT) then
         begin
            FExecTime := GetTickCount - FExecTime;
            FErrorMsg := Format(' TIMEOUT (%d msec) %s',[FExecTime,sErrExchangeTimeOutINI]);
         end;
         ...
      end;
   end;
end; { Execute }
```

For Delphi XE2 `ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT` is declared in `Winapi.WinInet`, `ESOAPHTTPException` is declared in `Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans`

---

As a side note, do determine your timeouts (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848428/retrieve-default-internet-timeout-values/30848749)):

```
procedure TFrmWininetTimeOuts.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  hSession     : HINTERNET;
  dwTimeOut    : DWORD;
  lBuflen      : Cardinal;
begin
  hSession := InternetOpen('usersession', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(hSession) then Exit;
  try
    lBufLen := SizeOf(dwTimeOut);
    if InternetQueryOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, @dwTimeOut, lBufLen) then
       Edit1.Text := IntToStr(dwTimeOut);
    if InternetQueryOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT, @dwTimeOut, lBufLen) then
       Edit2.Text := IntToStr(dwTimeOut);
    if InternetQueryOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, @dwTimeOut, lBufLen) then
       Edit3.Text := IntToStr(dwTimeOut);
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I am using THTTPRIO for my SOAP  communication.